# Is it true that old Spanish native speakers tend to pronounce "d" instead of "t"?

Tags: pronunciación

I've heard from some people that once lived in Spanish-speaking countries that old people in those countries usually speak a "d" sound instead of clearly speaking "t" sound when they get old, and they can't usually distinguish these two sounds.

I find this could be explained using a basic theory. Just consider how this two sounds are pronounced:

- [**"t"** (voiceless dental)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_dental_stop) should use your tongue to touch the back of the front teeth,
- and [**"d"** (voiced dental)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_dental_stop) should use your throat to pronounce.

When people get older, their teeth fall out. How can they pronounce the "t" sound clearly and accurately?

So I want to ask whether this is true.

Comment: If it were true, it would not only be a characteristic of spanish, but of ALL human languages.  Alas, I don't think this is universal.

Comment: There is such a difference between British English and American English (eg: water) and it is certainly not due to the speaker's age.

Comment: Welcome to Spanish Language. I've edited your question to correct spelling, grammar and punctuation. Please, note a question may get downvoted for these reasons. I've also added two links to Wikipedia to clarify your description of the  pronunciation of "t" and "d".

Comment: In my experience this is not true and the reasoning you propose is flawed. The main difference between the pronunciation of "t" and "d" is that the former is voiceless and the latter is voiced (and so a lack of front teeth doesn't make their pronunciation more difficult).

Answer (score 1):

I think this falls more into the category of the region. I have traveled to 2/3 of the States in Mexico and yes they might be a difference between pronunciation in different words but everything seems to come down to the part of the region you visit. People for example from the State of Oaxaca Mexico  tend to pronounce some words with the different sounds of others, a great example is when I was asking for direction, many people pronounce the Words 'S' like an 'h' like "eh que dije que fuera a la tienda" instead of "es que dije que fuera a la tienda".

Another state that I also visited was Guerrero which is nice tourist place where people would say words like "Pescado" as "Pescao" or "Pescaoh", regardless I would not consider this event occurring as you grow older but as a matter of where individual live and shared common words.